# MassTransit custom Query/Command topology for Request/Response mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm currently reworking a microservices-based solution into a modular monolith with four APIs (pro, cyclist, management, thirdparty). One of the changes that need to be done is adapting the topology of our broker (RabbitMQ) so it fits our requirements. These requirements are shown on the diagram below.
[image: Desired topology]
The idea is that we currently always use the Request/Response mechanism for all our commands and queries and Publish mechanism for events, meaning that we always expect a response, whenever issuing a query (obviously) or a command.

We want the topology to support scaling in a way that if API1 (any instance of this executable) has multiple instances

- commands/queries issued by any instance of the API1 will be executed by the consumers running in any instance of the API1 - this means that if both API1 and API2 executables have the same consumer, API2 consumers cannot execute commands/queries issued by the API2
- when scaling, queues for commands and queries should not be scaled, just new consumers will be added and round robin should fire up
- events are always received by all registered consumers so when scaling new queues are created

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create this topology in MassTransit but I can't seem to get rid of the default publish exchange of type fanout. Here's the code that I use for automatic registration of command/queries endpoints and queues

```
private static IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator AddNonEventConsumer<TConsumer>(
            IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator config,
            IRegistration context)
            where TConsumer : class, IConsumer
        {
            var routingKey = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
            var messageType = typeof(TConsumer)
                .GetInterfaces()
                ?.First(i => i.IsGenericType)
                ?.GetGenericArguments()
                ?.First();

            if (messageType == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"Message type could not be extracted from the consumer type. ConsumerTypeName=[{typeof(TConsumer).Name}]");
            }

            config.ReceiveEndpoint(e =>
            {
                // var exchangeName = new StringBuilder(messageType.FullName)
                //     .Replace($".{messageType.Name}", string.Empty)
                //     .Append($":{messageType.Name}")
                //     .ToString();
                
                var exchangeName = messageType.FullName;
                
                e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;

                e.Consumer<TConsumer>(context);
                e.Bind(exchangeName, b =>
                {
                    e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                    b.RoutingKey = routingKey;
                });
            });

            config.Send<TestCommand>(c =>
            {
                c.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(x => routingKey);
            });
            
            config.Publish<TestCommand>(c =>
            {
                c.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
            });

            return config;
        }
```

Again, we do want to use Request/Response mechanism for queries/commands and Publish mechanism for events (events are not a part of this question, it's a topic on its own, just queries/commands).

The question is - how do I configure endpoints and queues in this method in order to achieve the desired topology?

Alternative question - how else can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

> Cyclist? Pro? What kind of modular monolith is this anyway??

You're almost there, but need to configure a couple of additional items. First, when publishing, you'll need to set the routing key, which can be done using a routing key formatter. Also, configure the message type to use a direct exchange.

```cs
configurator.Send<TestCommand>(x =>
{
    x.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(context => /* something that gets your string, pro/cyclist */);
});

config.Publish<TestCommand>(c =>
{
    c.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
});
```

Also, if you're using custom exchange names, I'd add a custom entity name formatter. This will change the exchange names used for message types, so you can stick with message types in your application – keeping all the magic string stuff in one place.

```cs
class CustomEntityNameFormatter :
    IEntityNameFormatter
{
    public string FormatEntityName<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return new StringBuilder(typeof(T).FullName)
            .Replace($".{typeof(T).Name}", string.Empty)
            .Append($":{typeof(T).Name}")
            .ToString();
    }
}

config.MessageTopology
    .SetEntityNameFormatter(new CustomEntityNameFormatter());
```

Then, when configuring your receive endpoint, **do not** change the endpoint's exchange type, only the bound exchange to match the publish topology. Using an endpoint name formatter, custom for you application, you can configure it manually as shown.

```cs
var routingKey = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;

var endpointNameFormatter = new CustomEndpointNameFormatter();

config.ReceiveEndpoint(endpointNameFormatter.Message<TMessage>(), e =>
{
    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

    e.Bind<TMessage>(b =>
    {
        e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
        b.RoutingKey = routingKey;
    });

    e.Consumer<TConsumer>(context);
});
```

This is just a rough sample to get your started. There is a [direct exchange sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) on GitHub that you can look at as well to see how various things are done in there. You could likely clean up the message type detection as well to avoid having to do all the type based reflection stuff, but that's more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been trying to win this battle for last two days but i still fail to achieve my target topology. I pushed my test repository to github https://github.com/Arcanst/masstransit-tests . Not sure if you'd have time to quickly check it out but it's really small. What i'm missing now is the binding between the exchange and the queue - it doesn't contain the routing key and thus the message is published but never routed. Any ideas? Again - this repo contains a bit changed approach but based on what you wrote here. DependencyInjectors.cs is the one containing this code.

Comment: Commit 4d3a73995645eaf292b5a46f02d49d5c60885efc contains changes that create one exchange and one queue. The problem is that there are two bindings on that exchange - one is redundant (from exchange to exchange, routing key specified), the other is the one i want but incorrect because it leads from the exchange to the queue but doesn't have the routing key set up and i can't understand why this routing key isn't set on that binding. This would be the last piece of the puzzle for me.

Comment: That example is way too complex for me to look at, sorry. IF you have a SIMPLE example of what you're trying to that would help.

Comment: Well, the only two classes that would interest you are MassTransitTests.Shared/Startup/DependencyInjectors.cs and MassTransitTests.Shared/Startup/SharedStartup.cs but of course I understand that you can't spend so much time digging into issues like that. Thanks anyway!